# Possible trig identity?

Tags: trigonometry

Is there a trigonometric identity for $\sin(ab)$? Thanks in advance! I can't find it anywhere. Bothering me a lot.

For that matter, what about $\sin(a^{-1})$?

Both of these for cosine, too, but if you can get any one of these 4, that would be great.

[This](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ghwr4vtlum) might help get the creative juices flowing!

Comment: There's no general identity.

Comment: There is none, unless e.g. $\sin (ab)=\frac{1}{\csc (ab)}$ or $\sin (ab)=\pm\sqrt{1-\cos^2 (ab)}$.

Comment: My first instinct is to say "no" for the first question since using it on $\sin(a)$ would mean there would be a bunch of $\sin(1)$'s floating around

Comment: If you made it $\sin(\pi a b)$ would that help?

Comment: No, because $\sin (\pi ab)=\sin(cb)$ with $c=a\pi$

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the answer, and this isn't really a complete answer, it is more of a comment:

Perhaps use the fact that $sin(ab)$ is the imaginary part of $e^{iab}=(e^{ia})^b = (\cos a + i \sin a)^b$, and then use some binomial expansion formula. For example, taking $b=2$ recovers $\sin(2a)=2\cos(a)\sin(a)$, and similar expressions for other positive integers $b$ (I think chebyshev polynomials arise). Of course, $b$ need not be an integer, but there is still a binomial expansion for real numbers $b$, and maybe something can still be said, I don't know.